# Electron builder - Define linux version

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Im using electron which has already a production env running. For the last months I've been publishing normally with **Electron-builder** in `my ci.yml` file:

```
release-linux:
  stage: release
  image: electronuserland/builder:14
  before_script:
     - export ARCH="x64"
     - export BUILD_SCRIPT="build:linux"
     - apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential cmake
     - apt install -y libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev
```

After running the  `- apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential cmake` line there is the `libc6` package installed which installs with **latest** (`2.35`).

My production environment is running on Ubuntu **20.04 LTS**. I assume the docker image in which the release is made, is running on a newer version (asuming latest).

The problem is that I have some hardware devices which works correctly with `libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2` (which is the version that was automatically installed previously by the docker image). Now, for some reason I don't know, the image is pulling the latest version of `libc6` and my hardware devices stoped working.

- Is there any way to force **electron-builder** to use a specific Linux/Ubuntu version?
- Or maybe use the latest version of ubuntu but downgrading the `libc6` version (tried this one but failed). Any instructions on how to do this are apreciated.

Updating Ubuntu's version at production is **not an option** right now, so I think the solution should be working out with this package/library version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved out on its own randomly, but after some research, it was a `electron-builder` change which was causing the problem.

In this [commit changes log](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/commit/7d606aff59c964dc0af93c0f235abb0f3e258dea) we can see that `buildpack-deps` was changed from `buildpack-deps:22.04-curl` **(not working)** to `buildpack-deps:focal-curl` **(working)**.

That give us a clue to where to look at. Here the [official supported tags for Dockerfiles](https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps). Here we can see that `focal-curl` points to `20.04-curl` which I suppose have a different output than `20.04` by its own.

Then, looking at the gitlab jobs running with this ci configs, the `libc6` dependency worked with different versions in each case.
Our hardware works correctly with `libc6=2.31` which is used when `focal-curl` is set by `electron-builder` dockerfile, but not with `libc6=2.35` which is used by `20.04`.

This is not a solution, but it's the cause of the problem. Now working on how to setup the project to use only the correct configuration of `electron-builder`. Currently accepted to work with same config but being careful when releasing by watching which `libc6` version is working with.